# Need Help! Recognizing types of errors: Truncation and Roundoff

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am a little unclear on the difference between the two.

What exactly are they? As simplified as possible :)
How can i recognize them and identify parts of formulas or algorithms that would give rise to these types of errors

Answer (score 1):

The truncation errors are usually associated with *truncating* "something" infinite, that is,
$$
\text{something infinite} = \text{something finite} + \text{truncation error}.
$$
Typically, it is associated, e.g., with the discretization error when solving ODEs or PDEs.

The roundoff errors, as the name indicates, are associated with the rounding errors of the machine's finite precision arithmetic. First, even if we had by some miracle the exact data for our problem (neglecting, e.g., measurement errors) we cannot store them exactly since the computer arithmetic can represent only a finite subset of all $\mathbb{R}$. These errors are usually very small (relatively to the so-called machine precision). However, each operation ($+$,$-$,$\times$,$/$) is performed by a computer with the same relative error and they somehow propagate through the algorithm.

Summarizing: truncation error comes from restricting infinite stuff to a discrete approximation, roundoff error arises from storing real numbers and from arithmetic operations performed in the finite precision arithmetic used by computers.